# Image not showing in debugger

Tags: facebook-opengraph, akamai

I tried to debug my page with the Facebook debugger and the information received seems to be correct (as seen here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.dresorcaini.ro ). The name, the path and the size of the image eu.jpg are correctly shown.

Nevertheless, the image does not show. Instead, as it can be seen in the "object properties" in the above link of the debugger, returns this:

https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCGQKcvvrEtPgmc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dresorcaini.ro%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F09%2Feu.jpg

with 1x1 pixels, 43 bytes, and .gif.

What might be the problem, and how to fix it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a very likely cause for this behavior. The hosting provider has blocked the outgoing requests for free accounts so Akamaihd service can not get the picture; therefore it returns an empty GIF.
I hope this helps everybody.